# `+` operator within a regex seems to be more than just the greedy operator

Tags: ruby, regex, pry

I was doing some random Ruby reading, and had been messing around with different things in Ruby that does behind the scenes implicit conversions to an array. So within my pry console I had done this:

```
[1] pry(main)> class String
[1] pry(main)*   def to_ary
[1] pry(main)*     [100]
[1] pry(main)*   end
[1] pry(main)* end
```

Within the same pry session, if I do the following:

```
[14] pry(main)> /++/ === "whatever"
100
```

What is Ruby doing here?!

Comment: `pry` is up to something weird. If you look at the call stack in your `String#to_ary`, you'll see that it is all `pry` stuff and part of the stack appears to be an exception handler that is probably eating the `SyntaxError: target of repeat operator is not specified:` that the `/++/` literal should always produce.

Comment: @muistooshort hmm that is strange for sure, thanks for looking into it!

Comment: The culprit appears to be an [`Array.try_convert`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-c-try_convert) call, that will call `to_ary` when `pry` probably isn't expecting it to exist. I'm not certain though. I'd dig further but, well, it is a bit tedious :)